# In what order should i put objects to database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have database in mysql and connection to java with hibernate. I have 4 tables:
Clients 1 to many with Orders 
Orders 1 to many with OrdersProducts 
OrderProducts many to 1 with Products.
I have clients and products already in database. My program collects products and client from user and I want to add them to database. All I need to do is:
-add Order with ArrayList of OrderProducts
-add all OrderProducts
-update client ArrayList of Orders with new order
-update all Products with ArrayLists of OrderProduts
My question:
Is it matter which objects i put first to database and if so what should be correct sequence?

My entities below: (edited)

```
@Entity
public class Clients implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private int idClient;
     private String clientName, clientSurname, clientCompany;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "clients")
     private List<Orders> listOfOrders = new ArrayList<Orders>();
}

@Entity
public class Orders implements Serializable {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private int idOrder;
     private double totalAmount;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "idClientFK")
     private Clients clients;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orders")//, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     private List<OrdersProducts> listOfProductsInOrder = new ArrayList<OrdersProducts>();
}

@Entity
public class OrdersProducts implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idOrderProduct;
    private int productAmount;
    private float productsValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idOrderFK")
    private Orders orders;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProductFK")
    private Products products;
}

@Entity
public class Products implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idProduct;
    private String productName;
    private double productValuePerUnit;
    private String productUnit;
    private int productCount;
    private String productCompany;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private List<OrdersProducts> listOfOrdersProducts = new ArrayList<OrdersProducts>();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence to persist a new Order in the database will be:

- WHEN USER PUSH NEW ORDER BUTTON: Create a new Orders entity.

  - Update relation to Clients.
  - Add it to listOfOrders list in Clients entity (not necessary to persist an Order).
- WHEN USER ADD A NEW PRODUCT TO THE ORDER: Create an OrdersProducts entity.

  - Update relations to Orders and Products.
  - Add them to listOfProductsInOrder list in Order entity.
- WHEN USER PUSH CHECKOUT ORDER: Persist the Order entity.

But, you have to change:

```
@OneToMany
```

by:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

in the Orders entity.

Note: Better give names in singular to the model entities.

**EDIT**

Ok, I would implement bidirectional relations to increase flexibility:

- In your Orders entity you should have a ManytoOne relation to Clients entity.
- In your OrdersProducts you should have a ManytoOne relation to Orders and another to Products.

In general update all the relations before persist the an entity.

For these bidirectional relations the systax would be:

- Clients:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Clients implements Serializable {
  ...
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "idClientFK")
      private List<Orders> listOfOrders = new ArrayList<Orders>();
  }
  ```
- Orders:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Orders implements Serializable {
  ...
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "idOrderFK")
      private List<OrdersProducts> listOfProductsInOrder = new ArrayList<OrdersProducts>();
      @JoinColumn (referencedColumnName = "idclient")
      @ManyToOne
      private Clients idClientFK;
  }
  ```
- OrdersProducts:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class OrdersProducts implements Serializable {
  ...
      @JoinColumn (referencedColumnName = "idorderproduct")
      @ManyToOne
      private Products idProductFK;
      @JoinColumn (referencedColumnName = "idorder")
      @ManyToOne
      private Orders idOrderFK;
  }
  ```
- Products:

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Products implements Serializable {
  ...
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "idProductFK")
      private List<OrdersProducts> listOfOrdersProducts = new ArrayList<OrdersProducts>();
  }
  ```

If you have bidirectional relations you could persist an entire Orders entity or you could persist only one OrdersProducts entity each time. But if you have only unidirectional relations you will have to persist the Clients entity in order to persist one or more new or modified Orders for this client. And navigation across related entities will be restricted to father to children direction.

Comment: Willl Products and clients automatically connects with OrdersProducts and Orders or should I also manually add them to ArrayLists?

Comment: You always must to update the relation attributes manually before persisting. In general it's better to use bidirectional relations. If you are forced to use only unidirectional OneToMany relations, then to persist an OrdersProducts entity you would have to update the relation in Products and persist the Product entity (include cascade = CascadeType.ALL here too), but it is very weird. My advice is you to read a bit JPA documents. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29).

Comment: So I should change cascade to cascade.ALL in Products and when I add OrdersProducts to Products database will automatucally add foreign key? Its my first JPA project and I know that I have made a lot of mistakes. My next project will by much better.

Comment: I'd better redo the relations using bidireccional and cascade ALL, and then you will only have to persist the Order entity in order to persist the order and the order items. JPA wikibook will show you the way.

Comment: I changed my entities as you adviced me, (you can see it in my post). Should I add cascadeType.ALL to all OneToMany relations?

Comment: Only to these relations in entities you want its persist imply its children persist. For example in Order, or perhaps in Client, but never in Product.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.